# Python writing zlib compressed data

Tags: python, file, sorting, compression, zlib

The current code I am using is the following before we start:

```
with open(classFileName,"a+"): as openFile
    fileData = openFile.readlines()
    try:
        fileData = zlib.decompress(str(fileData))
    except:
        pass

with open(classFileName,"a+") as openFile:
    openFile.write(fileData)

with open(classFileName,"a+") as openFile:
    fileData = []
    fileData = openFile.readlines()
    fileData.append(mergedData)

    fileData = sorted((a.strip().split() for a in fileData),key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    fileData = os.linesep.join(p[0] + ' ' + p[1] for p in fileData)

    fileData = str(fileData)
    zlib.compress(fileData)

with open(classFileName,"w") as openFile:
    openFile.write(fileData)
```

However this actually throws an error saying expected a character buffer object on that last line.

An example of the file is as shown:

Reece 5
John 7
Alex 2

Any suggestions or help? I want to compress to reduce manipulating the scores. It looks better for the reason I am doing it don't worry about the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Python can't be changed  (nor does byte objects) - therefore, one can infere even without looking at the doc, that `zlib.compress` can't modify your `fileData{` inplace. The above snippet just records the original fileData.

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html):

> `zlib.compress(string[, level])` Compresses the data in string,
>   returning a string contained compressed data. level is an integer from
>   0 to 9 controlling the level of compression; 1 is fastest and produces
>   the least compression, 9 is slowest and produces the most. 0 is no
>   compression. The default value is 6. Raises the error exception if any
>   error occurs.

So,

```
 fileData = zlib.compress(fileData)
```

should work for you.